# Refreshing an excel workbook takes a very long time

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I need to be able to refresh an excel workbook, to make sure all the formulas have been calculated before trying to read data from it. I am using this code to do the update:

```
xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(<path_to_excel_workbook>)
wb.RefreshAll()
xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
wb.Save()
xlapp.Quit()
```

But it is extremely slow, in fact, I have been running it for several minutes and it still hasn't completed. Is there a faster way to refresh all of the formulas?

Comment: if you manually open the file.(i.e. through office) Does it take similar amount of time to recalculate and save?

Comment: @Atanas Atanasov Nope, it takes a couple of seconds to save because the file is so huge but not very long at all.

Comment: is your excel connected to external sources ?
I think xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone() might be the reason. is there a dialog that opens when you manually open the file? I believe some pop-up may appear while trying to update external data source that makes it impossible for the operation to complete. But I am just speculating. the com object should act the same way as if you open it manually.